# What type of data is the Java stack implemented as and how does it calculate on each type?

Tags: java, stack, implementation

I'm referring to the actually java compiler implementation here:

I guess the stack is implemented as a **C** struct, but what I really mean is:

How does java calculate with this structure? For example, if one local variable is of type string or pointer, and the other is a double, or an int, and java needs to operate on these variables, say add both, does it first convert both to the same type and then add, and return the value?

Would it be more or less like this:

```
struct var {
    dataType type;
    union{
        char c;
        int i;
        double d;
        void *p;
    } value;
}
```

where dataType is some enumeration of data types.

For example: Let's say variable A is a double, and variable B is an int, and C is again a double.

How is the bytecode generated for C = A + B? and how does the virtual machine operate with these different data types?

Comment: You could just compile some sample code and take a look at the bytecode...

Comment: Also, it's not clear what "adding variables of different types" has to do with the structure of the stack.  You seem to be asking about at least three unrelated topics (Java conversion semantics, bytecode generation, and the JVM stack).  Please could you edit your question to focus on **one** topic?

Comment: There are tomes written on compiler design and implementation. I suggest you get a hard-copy book or do some online research. When you have a more specific question, we can certainly help.

Comment: `How does java calculate with this structure?` it doesn't, the JVM does, which is usually written in C or C++, and I guess it'll look at  the stack as an array of machine words.

Comment: A modern JVM is not bound to actually emulate a stack-based processor on top of a register based architecture, it just has to generate equivalent results.  You're asking an awful lot of different questions at the same time :)

Answer (score 1):

Floating points (doubles) and integers are totally different datatypes and all modern processors have special operations for handling these datatypes. Also Java bytecode has an add operand for adding floating point (dadd) and an add operand for adding integers (iadd).

Now to your question:

```
double A = 1;
int B = 1;
double C = B + A;
```

Since the result C is a double the Java compiler will simply convert the B to a double. The bytecode would look something like this:

```
dload_1    // load double A
iload_3    // load int B
i2d        // convert int to double
dadd       // add doubles 
dstore 4   // store result to C
```

Comment: Very true for primitives; however, Object types are handled quite differently.

Comment: In the question only primitives are mentioned.

Comment: While primitives are a bit chunk of it, last I checked void* wasn't a primitive by far, and the closest thing it maps to in Java is a reference (which speaks to me as a class).  I guess other interpretations are possible, perhaps I read the question a bit differently (having focused more one the union in the data structure).

Comment: The question wasn't very clear :)

Comment: I'm with you on that.  It's hard to cover all the bases.

Answer (score 1):

Java does not coerce types as freely as C, so there is never a "convert string and int in such a way that they get added".

The Java type system is generally managed by string comparison (at one conceptual level, however, such items are often optimized away, and this level is a gross simplification).

So a method has a signature, which is represented in the '.class' object as a string.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  ...
}
```

would have the signature

```
main([Ljava.lang.String)V
```

meaning a name 'main' that takes an array '[' of an object 'L' of type that can be coerced into String 'java.lang.String' and returns nothing (a void) 'V'.

So to see if a set of parameters can be passed into this at runtime, the type of the object is checked to see if it is "assignable to" a String array.  Assignable to is a fancy way of saying, shares the type as a super class, or has the type as an interface, or one of the super classes has the type as an interface.

Due to this type of type checking, the JVM actually doesn't use the C style type checking for the elements within the JVM; however, it does do C style type checking for the elements that implement this environment (if that makes sense to you).

If you are very curious, you can read the [virtual machine specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/index.html), and perhaps even [download the JVM source code](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/hotspot/).  You will find that Java (due to polymorphisim) can't rely on static type checking in many instances, so a C compiler type verification wouldn't work anyway.